# turn a curl call into a javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, axios

How would I turn this curl request into an ajax call in javascript? (an answer in raw js or any library is fine)

**curl:**

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo":0, "bar": 0, "baz":"test"}' -X GET http://localhost:8080/public/v1/state/HelloWorld`

**The URL I tried in my ajax call (it gives a 404 error):**

`GET http://192.168.56.101:8080/public/v1/state/HelloWorld?foo=0&bar=0&baz=test`

**Code**

```
return axios.get(switchDomain + '/public/v1/state/HelloWorld', {
    params: {
      foo: 0,
      bar: 0,
      baz: "BER",
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log('perf response', response);
  });
```

Comment: **The URL I tried in my ajax call** - what ajax call? you haven't shown any code regarding the issue you are having

Comment: AJAX calls don't do anything special. If a GET request to http://192.168.56.101:8080/public/v1/state/HelloWorld?foo=0&bar=0&baz=test fails via AJAX, it's not AJAX/JS's fault. Visit http://192.168.56.101:8080/public/v1/state/HelloWorld?foo=0&bar=0&baz=test in your browser. Is there something there?

Comment: Yea just pasting the GET request into my browser fails as well. But it works with the curl call. So I'm assuming I'm not understanding something about the arguments / how the data is being passed

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `-d` will turn your CURL request into `POST` regardless of your `-X` option, so:

```
var req = new  XMLHttpRequest();
req.open( "POST", "http://localhost:8080/public/v1/state/HelloWorld", true);
req.send("foo=0&bar=0&baz=test");
```

Eventually you may need to add a content-type header after `req.open` and before `req.send`.

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Or as posted in your question, you may want to send it as JSON

```
var req = new  XMLHttpRequest();
req.open( "POST", "http://localhost:8080/public/v1/state/HelloWorld", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.send(JSON.stringify({
    foo: 0,
    bar: 0,
    baz: "test"
}));
```

Comment: In fairness, OP might not have been a Facebook *JavaScript* engineer... but yeah.

Comment: @ceejayoz well, since when do you need to be a JavaScript engineer (is that a thing? :P) to replace an URL in 3 lines of code? No offense to anyone!

Comment: That's the "but yeah" part of my comment. :-p

Comment: I can handle making an ajax call (or pasting a URL with params into my browser for that matter) it's interpreting the cURL call arguments that I'm unsure of.  That's why I made the GET request in ajax / my browser's URL), and when that didn't work looked up what the curl arguments were doing, and when I didn't see anything that would explain why the curl worked and ajax failed - came here to post

Comment: @DonnyP well, you should use `encodeURIComponent` on both the key and value of each parameter, I suppose. Also, as ceejayoz suggested, visit the address in your browser and see if you get a valid response, if not then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Also this answer still doesn't work, despite the curl working.

Comment: @DonnyP well you asked how to turn the curl request into xhr, so that's that. You said you can't access the address so there's another problem, obviously. Perhaps the machines you are using to send the requests are different or there are some preset headers on your curl command or something, or your server is configured to tell you not found when you're not authenticated. Things that come off the top of my head.

Comment: Alright think I figured it out.  That curl request is putting the parameters in the request *body* not the URL. This API doesn't interpret params in the header.

Comment: @DonnyP that's very weird, query string parameters are standard pretty much since the birth of the internet.

Comment: Yeah they definitely are standard for APIs.  This is not a standard one :( Anyway seems that is what the `-d` option in this curl request is doing...

Comment: Thanks for the help @php_nub_qq checking it out now. Finally got access to the API server's code to see what they are actually handling too

Comment: Strange - but the edited anser still 404's. Also if I make the curl request, and switch it from GET to POST, that 404's too...